# TMP differs from user variable on Windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-8.1

On my Windows machine I have a strange behavior.

The system variable `TEMP` and `TMP` are set to:

```
%SystemRoot%\TEMP
```

The user variable `TEMP` and `TMP` are set to:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Evaluating `%USERPROFILE%` in `cmd` gives me something like:

```
C:\Users\my.username
```

Evaluating `%TEMP%` and `%TMP%` in `cmd` gives me something (DOS) like:

```
C:\Users\my5336~1~AME
```

Can someone explain to me where `cmd` values originate from? Am totally confused.

I can find the `my5336~1~AME` value in the registry in `HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/DFP/Environment/`  but am not familiar with that.

---

**EDIT:**

Even after removing the entries from the registry and logging out and in, they still evaluate to the strange values.

And `[System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%tmp%")` in *PowerShell* gives me the strange values, too.

Answer (score 0):

User environment variables are stored under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

And system environment variables under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

What you have looks like a bit like a short file name

Comment: The basic problem is that none of these Environments reflect the values reported by `cmd`. Effectively I have no idea where the values come from.

Comment: If you follow the instructions here: https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500 to get the environment variable editor, do you see the corrupted versions of the environment variables or are they as they should be?

Comment: If I set a environment variable (`TMP`) for the User `cmd` does no longer find that variable while others (`TEMP`) are still available.